# 3D Particles Ball

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

If I'd like to make a circle with particles, I'd define random coordinates for particles like this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i != 100; i++)
{
var angle:Number    = Math.random() * 360;
var r:Number        = 600;
var nX:Number       = r * Math.cos(angle / 180 * Math.PI);
var nY:Number       = r * Math.sin(angle / 180 * Math.PI);
}
```

But I want to make a ball with particles on 3d space but I don't know how to define random coordinates for particles. Radius is fixed again but there should be a "nZ" value. Can you help me to define these coordinates?

```
for(var i:int = 0; i != 100; i++)
{
var angle:Number    = Math.random() * 360;
var r:Number        = 600;
var nX:Number       = ???
var nY:Number       = ???
var nZ:Number       = ???
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spherical coordinates are what you want.

You need two angles:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i != 100; i++)
{
    var azimuthAngle:Number    = Math.random() * 360;
    var elevationAngle:Number  = (Math.random() * 180) - 90;
    var r:Number = 600;
    var nX:Number =
         r * Math.cos(azimuthAngle / 180 * Math.PI) * Math.sin(elevationAngle / 180 * Math.PI);
    var nY:Number =
         r * Math.sin(azimuthAngle / 180 * Math.PI) * Math.sin(elevationAngle / 180 * Math.PI);
    var nZ:Number =
         r * Math.cos(elevationAngle / 180 * Math.PI);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome.  I think you just suggested an edit of the second line, correct?  (Someone did, anyway.)  Elevation ranges from +90 degrees to -90 degrees, not 0 to 360.  Think North Pole and South Pole and their latitudes.

Comment: I edited because only "north pole" appeared with this angle. I need both :)

Comment: I think it works?  If Math.random() * 180 is zero, then elevationAngle is -90.  If it's 180, then it's +90, correct?  Math.random() outputs a number between 0 and 1, correct?

Comment: John you're correct Math.random() Returns a pseudo-random number n, where 0 <= n < 1.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll confess I don't know a lick of ActionScript; I cheated and used the syntax in the example. :)